# How to have more post in a page than in your home page

Tags: query, customization, posts, homepage, pages

I am new to the world of WordPress.
I own a new site and I'd like my home page to display the latest news and articles (which I accomplished to set in Settings > Reading), but I'd like another page to display all posts (not the whole post but a summary) without the need to press "previous page".

e.x.
If I have 8 posts and I set maximum posts to be 4 in the settings menu, my home will have 4 posts. But I'd like the other page to have all 8 posts in summary without the need to press previous page to read other posts.
How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
<?php
    if(have_posts()) {
        while(have_posts()) {
            the_post(); the_excerpt();
        }
    }
?>
```

And of course, read the documentation for further info:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page
- http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a custom loop. Create a new [template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and in that template file you must run a [custom loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) like this:

```
 <?php
 $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'post'
     'posts_per_page' => -1 //setting -1 will return all posts
 );

 //query for our posts
 $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

 //if we have posts, loop them
 if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post(); ?>
         //your html here
         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
         <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

 <?php
 endwhile;
 endif;

 //even though WP_Query doesn't effect the main loop, reset it as precaution
 wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

Unfortunately it isn't easy to do this without creating a custom template file but you can find all the resources you need to piece this together. Best of luck!